# Why do all activation functions have positive slope?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, gradient-descent

I am wondering why all the common activation functions tend to increase with x (or stay flat like ReLU). I have not come across any that are inversely proportional to x, or that have some other shape. For example, wouldn't `1-tanh(x)^2` be a useful sometimes? Or `sech(x)`? These are functions that peak when x=0, and minimize as abs(x) increases.

Maybe I am overlooking something here, or there are other libraries that provide these functions out of the box?
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/activations

The practical reason for my question is that I am building a shallow NN to recognize palindromes, and I know that these activation functions would be useful assuming gradient descent still works.

Comment: Gaussian/radial functions decrease after a point. Tensorflow documentation shouldn't be taken as a comprehensive survey of the deep learning literature.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll have to look into the literature more.